# Printing Rich Layout Like Spreadsheets

Tags: c++, qt

I'm looking for a solution that would allow me to print from a C++/Qt app content like an invoice.

To be clear, I'm not asking how I can manipulate excel spreadheets.  I am looking to
take my app data and **PRINT OUT [to paper]** something like an invoice that is **nicely formatted**.

I need good formatting/layout capability.  Need: lines, borders, shading, text style(color,font, weight)...thus rich formatting abilities.

What is a workable solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[QGridLayout](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qgridlayout.html) can be used to create Excel-like "spreadsheet" form. You have control on where each of your info/widgets goes.

To print the layout, place the layout and its content in a QWidget then use [render](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qwidget.html#render) to paint it onto a [QPrinter](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qprinter.html), which is a QPaintDevice.

Comment: Thanks but my main concern is how to get it printed on paper with rich formatting.  A grid is a grid.  If you've seen an invoice before it is obvious that some grids must turn invisible, others need lines and borders of different weight, etc.  I don't see how QGridLayout offers this.  It only allows a simple grid with some minor formatting like color text, and background color.

Comment: The layout itself doesn't do formatting. But the widgets you placed in it do. For example, place QFrames into the grids and specify shape and width of the frames and you have some basic grid made of boxes. Place your data widgets in the frames and you have the sheet.